# Piwik (Matomo) installation in an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, analytics, matomo

I have to install Piwik (now Matomo) analytics tool in an AngularJS project. I am using windows and I have to do it in my local environment. I am an absolute noob in this backend stuff So, cannot figure out how to proceed.

The brief idea that I have got till now is that I'll have to use node.js with express.js to setup the local server. Also, I have to use mySQL along with it to store the data.

So, my question is that how can I do the same? Any relevant resources will be really helpful.

Comment: piwik is a different tool.. what do you mean by installation in an angular js app? You can use piwik in angularjs app

Comment: Installation is not the right word. Integration is the right one.